# Formatting mathematical functions

Tags: java

I have whole bunch of mathematical functions being output from a program in this format:

```
(704253724578.0182000000000000 .* (mydivide (mydivide (mydivide (mysqrt (- X13 X11)) (mydivide X18 X15)) (* (square (mydivide (* X1 X20) X19)) X2)) (mydivide (* (* X1 X20) (mydivide X25 X15)) X9))) + 77.2424201451314200
```

I need to write a script to convert them into somewhat readable formats like this:

```
(704253724578.0182000000000000 * ( ((sqrt(X13-X11) / (X18/X15)) /((((X1*X20)/X19)^2) * X2))/ (((X1 * X20) * (X25 / X15)) / X9)) ) + 77.2424201451314200
```

Any ideas on what is the best way to go about doing this in java? Or are there any other better tools to do this besides java?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a term-algebra to infix notation problem, which is language independent.

Comment: When using powers/exponents, don't use the `^` character, it doesn't do what you think it does. if you need `x` raised to the power of `2` (e.g. `x ^ 2`), you should use `Math.pow(x, 2)`. The `^` operator is actually a ["bitwise exclusive OR"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: right... I am not actually trying to do the math. I am just simply trying to format the strings to go from prefix notation to infix notation. Any idea on how to format the strings? Thanks!

Comment: That is just a question of recursive walk of the s-expression. Then apply the wright transformations with respect to the format of the sub-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ruby and one nice gem named "sexpistol" that allows you to handle s-expressions.

I hacked a solution for you :

```
require 'sexpistol'
require 'pp'

exp="(704253724578.0182000000000000 .* (mydivide (mydivide (mydivide (mysqrt (- X13 X11)) (mydivide X18 X15)) (* (square (mydivide (* X1 X20) X19)) X2)) (mydivide (* (* X1 X20) (mydivide X25 X15)) X9))) + 77.2424201451314200"

parser = Sexpistol.new
tree= parser.parse_string(exp)

SYM={
    :".*" => :*,
    :*   => :*,
    :"+" => :"+",
    :- => :-,
    :mydivide => :/,
    :square => "^2",
    :mysqrt => "mysqrt"
    }

def isPrefix sexp
    return true if SYM[sexp.first]
    return false    
end

def p2i sexp
    if sexp.is_a? Array
        if isPrefix(sexp)
            op,lhs,rhs =sexp
            case op
            when :square
                return [p2i(lhs),SYM[op]]
            when :mysqrt
                return [:mysqrt,p2i(lhs)]
            else
                return [p2i(lhs),SYM[op],p2i(rhs)]
            end
        else
            lhs,op,rhs=sexp
            return [p2i(lhs),SYM[op],p2i(rhs)]
        end
    else
        return sexp
    end
end

pp parser.to_sexp(p2i(tree)).first
# prints : (704253724578.0182 * ((((mysqrt (X13 - X11)) / (X18 / X15)) / ((((X1 * X20) / X19) ^2) * X2)) / (((X1 * X20) * (X25 / X15)) / X9))) + 77.24242014513142
```

If you write a paper, you can acknowledge me !

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I figured it out using stacks to push and pop the terms in java.

Comment: Maybe you could validate the answer (working solution). Thx !